# What is the preferred way to implement a factory method in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, factory

A newbie question: I have a hierarchy of classes with some virtual functions and I am trying to implement a factory method, but I am not sure what is the best way:

1. Return a raw pointer from the factory method and wrap it into a smart pointer in the calling method
2. Return a smart pointer from the factory
3. Return a proper object from the factory (but is it going to copy the derived class correctly?) and assign it to a local object in the calling method
4. Return a reference from the factory (but how to create the object in the factory method without a memory leak?)

I would be grateful for an example of a factory method and a minimal client, which is effective and doesn't leak memory.

My background is C# and Java, so I am a bit lost with memory management in C++ atm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Options 3 and 4 are out from the start because they simply don’t work: 3 slices the object, 4 creates memory leaks or invalid references.

From the other two methods, I strongly prefer 2: return a smart pointer. In fact, strive to avoid raw pointers completely, if possible. Unfortunately, C++ makes this a lot to write (and this is not a trivial objection! Anybody who has ever written object-oriented code in C++ and has used smart pointers throughout shares my pain) – but the alternative is even more pain.

Of course, there *is* alternative 5: use raw pointers and a garbage collector.

Comment: Consistantly returning `boost::shared_ptr` is often a good idea actually. And it is not that great a pain (at least much less a pain than raw pointers). Since most polymorphic hierarchies are made up of non copyable objects (ie. which don't provide a `clone` method), the shared semantics are often what you want. Beware of cyclic dependancies though.

Comment: @Alexandre: in my experience, cyclic dependencies are really, really rare. At least when you’re not using events/signals. And there weak references (i.e. common pointers) might consistently be the best solution. Don’t know. Never done that in C++, to be honest.

Comment: Sure, they are rare. But when they kick in, you're in trouble. Weak pointers are supposed to cure this, but you never know in the presence of cyclic references what to design as weak. So this is a potential major issue.

Comment: I prefer using unique_ptr, as it more strongly enforces ownership.

Comment: @null Agreed. This answer predates widespread availability of C++11, otherwise it would have made this preference very clear.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Sorry, I should have made it clear that I was responding to the other comments recommending shared_ptr, and not to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

well my taste go to returning a smart pointer. [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403786) is a link to an example Abstract factory that returns a smart pointer.

my2c

Answer (score 3):

I prefer method 1 because it's more flexible. However, whether you return the raw pointer or the smart pointer is really just a matter of object usage. For example, you might want to return a raw pointer because you know that the object will sometimes be used once and immediately deleted in the same code block. In that case, there is no need to incur the overhead of contructing a smart pointer object. But if the lifetime of the object is always uncertain and you're worried about memory leaks, then by all means use method 2. Methods 3 and 4 are incorrect.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: there is little to no overhead in using a `auto_ptr`, and once C++0x kicks in a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Matt: perhaps little, but not zero.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: I do maintain the zero. Typical implementation, `auto_ptr` is just a pointer. Its destructor invocation requires a check... except if the compiler can prove it's unnecessary (example: you access the object, then it means the pointer is non-null, otherwise you invoked undefined behavior). And thus the destructor turns out to be a call to delete, which you would have performed anyway. Oh and I obviously forgot NRVO, so that no copy is involved in the process. Mind, I don't know if any compiler is "evil" enough to assume non-null pointers based on user access, but it is condoned.

Comment: @Matt: there's at least reference count init.

Comment: @ThomasMcLoed: **NO!** There is no reference count in an `auto_ptr`, a `scoped_ptr` or a `unique_ptr`: there is a UNIQUE owner of the resource, which can be transferred (apart from `scoped_ptr`) but that is all. Not all smart pointers are similar!

Comment: @Matt, thanks for setting me straight on the pointer classes (pointer pointers, hehe). But it's still not zero, unless you can guarentee inline of the constructor/destructor calls.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: they are generally inline because the classes are necessarily template.

Comment: @Matt, just checked the disassembly release build on construct/destruct of auto_ptr on VS2010. By golly, you're spot on. Zero overhead in memory and op codes. I stand corrected.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need memory management, there is no other viable choice. However you may not need memory management from within the factory method.

The main issue with smart pointers is their absence of covariance, which is pain when implementing a `clone` virtual method. Unfortunately the covariance rule is not relaxed in C++0x so it remains an issue.

On the other hand, returning a raw pointer and leaving it up to the caller to wrap it up, is opening the door to bugs (even though it's the approach Boost elected for its clones).

Personally, I would suggest:

- the infamous `auto_ptr` or a plain pointer that the caller should wrap in C++03
- a `unique_ptr` as soon as your compiler gets it

The latter combine most advantages (leaving covariance aside), and includes little to no performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

After having struggled with method 1, I can assure you that method 2, either returning `boost::shared_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` (usually the former is what you want, if you don't have access to `std::unique_ptr`) is what I wholeheartedly recommand.